# Reinforcement learning, Q-learning to determine order to cast spells optimally?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

If I have a wizard who has 20 spells, each of which does different things, sometimes direct damage, sometimes disabling, sometimes protecting etc.  He has a fight with 10 orcs and I want to determine an optimal order of spell casting to kill the orcs as fast as possible.

Would Q learning help with this problem?

I could start with the initial state of 20 spells and then each following state would be which spell I have left and the final state would be the wizard or orcs dead.  Does that make any sense or am I trying to use the wrong AI algorithm for the job?

Comment: If a spell is used earlier, can you use it again?

Comment: lets say no for this example

Comment: Please, ask this question on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/). If you do that, please, delete the question from here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. You are looking for a trajectory of actions that alter the state. I.e. your player and orc health in such a way that you get a reward for a particular state occurring. I.e. killing the orc.